# Create python behave context manually

Tags: python, selenium, bdd, python-behave

I'd like to test python behave scenarios by manually calling before_all, after_all, etc to start the selenium webdriver and test manually so I can see the error messages displayed in realtime.

How do I create a valid behave context object programmatically that I can pass to these scaffolding methods as a parameter without just calling behave from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to have a look at the Context class:

https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/behave/runner.py